# App Engine service with apollo-express-server v2.x.x serving React app statically

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, graph, apollo-server

Rather than having an issue, this is more of a knowledge question. I've been diving deep on GAE's docs, Youtube videos and posts, on how to serve a full `MERN stack` app from a single App Engine service.

I honestly don't have a fine-grained understanding of what App Engine deployment does behind the scenes, but I understand that it exposes your service at port *8080* from a default route assigned (i.e. https://xxxxxxxx.uc.r.appspot.com).

Based on this knowledge, I thought it would be totally possible to statically serve a built React app and handle incoming queries from this same app through `/graphql` endpoint.

For instance:

1. This solves CORS since everything shares the same origin.
2. You limit yourself to a single App Engine service which allows you to remain on the free tier service :)

This is my project structure:

```
root/
 app/
  node_modules/
  build/ <----- React app built
  src/
  App.js
  index.js
  ...
 server/ <----- In here is the Apollo Express Server v2.x.x serving app/build generated above^
  index.js
 package.json
 node_modules/
 app.yaml <---- This file tells App Engine what to do and which routes to expose
 ...
```

My app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs12

env_variables:
  PORT: 4000

handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: app/build/index.html
    upload: app/build/index.html
  - url: /
    static_dir: app/build
  - url: /graphql
    script: auto <---- Supposedly App Engine is smart enough to understand what to do with this route.
```

I am just not being able to query my App Engine service back from the served to React app.

Does anyone know if what I'm doing is even possible, or there's just no way to configure App Engine with Apollo Server to serve a static webapp + expose a `/graphql` endpoint at the same time.

Any suggestions or ideas are extremely welcome!

--------------------------------- Update ---------------------------------

After ***GAEfan*** suggestion, I updated the `app.yaml` file:

Yeah okay! I think this is indeed working, I just still get a few errors on the console about `resources not found` so, here is the internal structure of the `build/`

```
build/
 static/
  css/
  js/
 asset-manifest.json
 favicon.ico
 index.html
 logo192.png
 manifest.json
 robots.txt
 service-worker.js
```

I already added to this suggestion `json|txt|map|ico` resources in the same fashion.

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|json|txt|map|ico))$
  static_files: app/build/\1
  upload: app/build/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|json|txt|map|ico)$
```

This resolved the not found resources issue. And your wildcards already resolved the /graphql endpoint. For some reason, the WebSocket handshake is not being correctly established, but I'm not sure if that's a direct limitation from App Engine, or that the protocol is blocked by default.

Does anyone have knowledge of Websockets over App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still more questions, but I'll add this as a partial/temporary answer...

Your first 2 url handlers in `app.yaml` are duplicates.  URL handling with match the first one, and send everything to `...index.html`.  I assume you have some `js`, `css`, or other static files in the build directory.  Those will never be made available to the browser.  So, you need to use better regex routing, with wildcards, etc.

Let's do these one at a time:

```
handlers:
  - url: /$  # this '$' ends the match, so the url matches only the root domain
    static_files: app/build/index.html
    upload: app/build/index.html
```

Next, let's test for `.js`, `.css`, etc.:

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js))$
  static_files: app/build/\1
  upload: app/build/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)$
```

Then (assuming you have `graphql` working properly, you can send all other requests there:

```
- url: /graphql
  script: auto
```

or even:

```
- url: /(.*) # catches everything else!
  script: auto
```

Show the files or directory tree inside your `/build` directory, and we can make sure we've accounted for everything.

Comment: Thanks mate! This is definitely what was going on with respect to correctly serving the static files. Now I only have the Websocket issue which I detailed above.